# Obtain the sum of count of multiple schema and tables in one query in mysql

Tags: mysql

The query belows return 4 rows and it's good. But i need also to sum the results of all the counts in the same query. How to achieve it? I've tried different things but i get sintax errors.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema3`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema4`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Fewer keystrokes:

```
SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4,
       s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 AS total
    FROM ( SELECT
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1 ) AS s1,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1 ) AS s2,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema3`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1 ) AS s3,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `schema4`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1 ) AS s4
         ) AS counts;
```

If there is a performance question, be sure to have `INDEX(state, level)` on each table.  (The order of the columns in the index does not matter in this case.)

If this is just one of many clumsy queries, you may want to reconsider having multiple databases (schemas) for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your sub-queries and put a `SELECT` clause on it.

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1) s1
,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1) s2
,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema3`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1) s3
,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema4`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1) s4
```

That should give you single row with 4 columns in it.

---

If you need sum of them in single query then use below query.

You can put them into a `select` clause and it should give you `sum` of it. here is an example.

```
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema3`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `schema4`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
) tmp
```

Comment: Negative vote is acceptable, but without mentioning a reason is BIG DEMOTIVATION to new contributor like me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly solution:

```
SELECT MAX(tmp.col1) as col1,
       MAX(tmp.col2) as col2,
       MAX(tmp.col3) as col3,
       MAX(tmp.col4) as col4,
       MAX(tmp.col1) + MAX(tmp.col2) + MAX(tmp.col3) + MAX(tmp.col4) as total
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS col1, NULL as col2, NULL as col3, NULL as col4
          FROM `schema1`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL as col1, COUNT(*) AS col2, NULL as col3, NULL as col4
          FROM `schema2`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL as col1, NULL as col2, COUNT(*) AS col3, NULL as col4
          FROM `schema3`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL as col1, NULL as col2, NULL as col3, COUNT(*) AS col4
          FROM `schema4`.`table` WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1) tmp
```

This will give you something like:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 100 |

It's not very efficient, but it gets the job done.